# number of 1's in 32 bit number

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I am lookin for a method to have number of 1's in 32 bit number
without using a loop in between.
can any body help me and provide me the code or algorithm 
to do so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: e.g. you want to like from 2344 to 2,3,4,4?
please clarify with your input and required output

Answer (score 44):

See [`Integer.bitCount(int)`.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int)) You can refer to the source code if you want to see how it works; many of the `Integer` class's bit twiddling routines are taken from [*Hacker's Delight.*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654)

Comment: Yes! Why use an exotic bit hack, when there's a method already available.

Comment: Using the builtin will also make it easier for future versions of JVM to figure out that the SSE4.2 POPCNT instruction can be used for this.

Comment: I was about to post an answer similar to Michael Foukarakis', because that's how I did it before Integer.bitCount() was implemented.  Thanks for drawing my attention to the new method.

Answer (score 8):

See the canonical reference: [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)

Comment: Just keep in mind that Java ints are *always* signed, and modify accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Short, obscenely optimized answer (in C):

```
int pop(unsigned x) {
   x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
   x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
   x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
   x = x + (x >> 8);
   x = x + (x >> 16);
   return x & 0x0000003F;
}
```

To see why this magic works, see *The Quest for an Accelerated Population Count* by Henry S. Warren, Jr. chapter 10 in *Beautiful Code*.

Comment: But the question was about Java and in Java there is no unsigned 32-bit int type, and this doesn't work with Java's signed 32-bit int.

Comment: As far as I can see, Java is not mentioned in the question. And maybe I'm wrong, but tags should not be used for restricting a question to a given language.

Comment: IMO you're wrong. If a question is tagged Java, what else does that mean, other than that the question is about Java? Maybe the questioner should also mention in the text that they're talking about Java, but if they don't, I don't think it follows that we should pretend it wasn't tagged Java. If you can assume a C answer is acceptable, then I can assume a GCC-only C answer is acceptable and say to use __builtin_popcount. But that doesn't help the questioner much ;-)

Comment: For java, there is an unsigned right bit shift (>>>). I _think_ that would give you the correct result. Though perhaps not the result you'd expect.

Comment: Replace the signed shift (`">>"`) with an unsigned shift (`">>>"`), and this code is exactly what's used in Java's `Integer.bitCount(int)` method.

Answer (score 3):

Split the 32 bit number into four 8 bit numbers (see bit shifting operator, casting etc.)

Then use a lookup with 256 entries that converts the 8 bit number into a count of bits set. Add the four results, presto!

Also, see what Mitch Wheat said - bit fiddling can be a lot of fun ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can define it recursively:

```
int bitcount(int x) {
  return (x==0) ? 0 : (x & 1 + bitcount(x/2));
}
```

The code above is not tested, and probably only works for x>=0. Hopefully, you will get the idea anyways...

Comment: -1 for using recursion when "no looping" was requested. Sure, it's not using a loop construct, but it still runs in non-O(1) time.

Comment: Sorry. The question resembled a homework problem to me and I wanted to provide a different view. For any performance critical as well as most non-theoretical applications, go for the bit-twiddling solutions!

Comment: the classical one is:

return (x==0) ? 0 : (1 + bitcount(x & (x - 1)));

Answer (score 3):

My personal favourite, directly from [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html):

```
v = v - ((v >> 1) & 0x55555555);
v = (v & 0x33333333) + ((v >> 2) & 0x33333333);
c = ((v + (v >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
```

Comment: NB: This won't work correctly with Java's signed int type -- but the basic idea is the one used by the library.

Comment: I think you want >>> instead of >>.

Comment: @finnw: I suppose you mean in Java (since no such operator exists in C, where I first saw/used the trick), in that case you're right, maintaining the sign is wrong.

Comment: @Michael, yes I am assuming Java (the question is tagged as java)

Answer (score 2):

Following is JDK 1.5 implementation of of Integer.bitCount

```
public static int bitCount(int i) {
    // HD, Figure 5-2
i = i - ((i >>> 1) & 0x55555555);
i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >>> 2) & 0x33333333);
i = (i + (i >>> 4)) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
i = i + (i >>> 8);
i = i + (i >>> 16);
return i & 0x3f;
}
```